# Avoiding Google Scholar block for crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have used the following python scripts to crawl google scholar from python:

```
import urllib

filehandle = urllib.urlopen('http://www.techyupdates.blogspot.com')

for lines in filehandle.readlines():
   print lines

filehandle.close()
```

but I am doing it repeatedly so I am getting blocked by the site-google scholar saying:

> This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS). The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.  In the meantime, solving ....

Is there an easy way to avoid this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you read __and__ understand the Google Terms of Service?

Comment: Yes.  Don't violate the terms of service.  Is this data available to you some other way?  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I am using to find google distance between two pair of words.. I am not doing anything wrong with it. It is just that I am sending repeated requests from my computer

Comment: Then why not use some other piece of content?  Even something that you cache locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[edit]*

Put some kind of throttling into your script so you lightly load Google Scholar (wait for 60s or 600s or 6000s between queries, for example).

And I do mean **lightly** load Google Scholar. If caching the Google Scholar results is possible, that would also reduce the Google Scholar load.

You should also look at batch processing, so you can run your crawl overnight at a steady but slow speed.

The goal is that Google Scholar should not care about your additional queries, thereby fulfilling the spirit of the ToS if not the letter. But if you can fulfill both, that would be the Right Thing to Do.

Comment: Figuring out how to circumvent the letter of the ToS while still clearly violating the spirit is not the kind of thing that should be condoned.  They don't want people flooding them with requests, so the right thing to do is to not flood them with requests.

Answer (score 1):

Store the file locally? You can also write a quick Python webserver to serve the file then, in case you need the HTTP connection. And yes, I agree, reading and trying to understand the error message helps, too...